# Error installing torch==1.8.0+cu111 in Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install PyTorch with CUDA support (torch==1.8.0+cu111) in a Colab notebook. However, I'm encountering an error during the installation process. Here is the code snippet that triggers the error:

```
import subprocess

CUDA_version = [s for s in subprocess.check_output(["nvcc", "--version"]).decode("UTF-8").split(", ") if s.startswith("release")][0].split(" ")[-1]
print("CUDA version:", CUDA_version)

if CUDA_version == "10.1":
    torch_version_suffix = "+cu101"
elif CUDA_version == "10.2":
    torch_version_suffix = "+cu102"
else:
    torch_version_suffix = "+cu111"
# pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
!pip install torch==1.8.0{torch_version_suffix} torchvision==0.9.0{torch_version_suffix} -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html ftfy reg
```

gives me the following error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.0+cu111 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.11.0+cpu, 1.11.0+cu102, 1.11.0+cu113, 1.11.0+cu115, 1.11.0+rocm4.3.1, 1.11.0+rocm4.5.2, 1.12.0, 1.12.0+cpu, 1.12.0+cu102, 1.12.0+cu113, 1.12.0+cu116, 1.12.0+rocm5.0, 1.12.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.12.1, 1.12.1+cpu, 1.12.1+cu102, 1.12.1+cu113, 1.12.1+cu116, 1.12.1+rocm5.0, 1.12.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.0+cpu, 1.13.0+cu116, 1.13.0+cu117, 1.13.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0+rocm5.2, 1.13.1, 1.13.1+cpu, 1.13.1+cu116, 1.13.1+cu117, 1.13.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.1+rocm5.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.0+cpu, 2.0.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.0+cu117, 2.0.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.0+cu118, 2.0.0+rocm5.3, 2.0.0+rocm5.4.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.1+cpu, 2.0.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.1+cu117, 2.0.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.1+cu118, 2.0.1+rocm5.3, 2.0.1+rocm5.4.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.8.0+cu111
```

I have verified that the CUDA version in my environment is 11.8.
I have a Nvedia 1650Ti Graphic card

Can someone please help me understand why I'm unable to install torch==1.8.0+cu111 in my Colab environment? Is there an alternative or workaround I can use to install this specific version with CUDA support?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

I tried to install it and the attempts are displayed in the codes in the form of comments

Answer (score 2):

Your installation command appears to have some weird filler stuff, like  `{torch_version_suffix}`, and at the end it says `ftfy reg`. Who is Reg, and what did someone fix for them?

You could try this:

`pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

(from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/))